# PostgreSQL data warehouse: create separate databases or different tables within the same database?

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse

We seek to run cross-table queries and perform different type of merges. For cross-database queries we need to establish connection every time.

Comment: I don't see any relation to (tagged) Python.

Comment: We are using python for development.We can also create a data playground where we can join different tables from different databases.

Comment: But where is the relation to **this question**? If it is Python related then show us related Python code!

Comment: Use schemas rather than databases.

Answer (score 3):

So to answer your question,
we should create multiple(different)tables within same database.
because cross database operation is not supported(for ex. In short you can't do the join on 2 tables in different database)

But if you want to segregate your data within same database you can create different schemas/layer .and create your tables under that.

for ex.

**1st load landingLayer.tablename

2nd transformation goodDataLayer.tablename

3rd transformation widgetLayer.tablename**